# g++ cannot find main function for simple "hello world" program

Tags: lubuntu, compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I have been trying to compile a simple hello world program in C++ on my lubuntu laptop. I use the command `g++ -o out cta.cpp` but I always get the error message below..

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have made sure I have a main function, here is the entire program..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The laptop I am using is an ex-chromebook where I have overwritten the original OS using the instructions on [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxsckwmRhfw).

I have made sure that gcc and g++ are both the same version and both are in the usr/bin directory. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both. I am performing the commands from the same directory as cta.cpp, and I've made sure I've gotten the name of the file right. I am not sure what else to check.

*How can I get my program to compile?*

Comment: try `g++ -Wall -Werror myfile.cpp -o myfile.o`, but it compiled fine on stock 18.04.

Comment: `$ g++ cta.cpp -o out` : OK, the executable *out* is created.

Comment: The *simplest* explanation is that the `cta.cpp` file in your current directory isn't the one that contains your source code; please eliminate that (for example, by executing `cat cta.cpp`) before we go down the rabbit hole of more exotic explanations

Comment: @steeldriver You're mostly right. The issue was that atom wasn't saving the file, but didn't throw an error or anything. Sorry for all the trouble. I am going to look into what's causing this.

Comment: @LuminousNutria thanks for the update - if you have time, please consider writing an answer in case others have the same issue